# Performance of MYSQL WHERE DATE(time) = 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table 'Tasks' with a DATETIME column `approve_time`. I have an index on said column.

If I were to write a query of the form:

```
SELECT task_id, task_desc, task_owner, approve_time 
  FROM Tasks
 WHERE DATE(approve_time) = '2011-08-31'
```

My question is about the performance of such a query:

Does MYSQL index DATETIME columns in a way that allows constraining by the date component to be fast?

Or does MYSQL know how to optimize the query into something like the following?

```
WHERE approve_time >= '2011-08-31 00:00:00'
  AND approve_time <  '2011-09-01 00:00:00'
```

Or does the query incur a tablescan?

Comment: You can omit time portion in your second query (`approve_time >='2011-08-31'`). In this case it will still use the index.

Comment: Note you can rewrite `WHERE approve_time >= '2011-08-31 00:00:00'
  AND approve_time <  '2011-09-01 00:00:00'` into `WHERE approve_time BETWEEN '2011-08-31 00:00:00' AND '2011-08-31 23:59:59'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does MYSQL index DATETIME columns in a way that allows constraining by the date component to be fast?

**NO**

> Or does MYSQL know how to optimize the query into something like the following?

**YES**

---

the second query will lead to range filter,
try

```
explain extended query_1; <--- number of rows sent for scan is more, 
                               which should be aLL rows
```

vs

```
explain extended query_2;
```

the value of `DATE(approve_time)` only can determined after the function applied to column approve_time in all the row, which mean there is not going to make use on index

Comment: To be clear, the optimizer does not know how to translate query_1 to query_2, right?

Comment: Yes, because the results of date function is yet to determine